# 2D and 3D versions of GaussianQuadratureWeights?

Tags: numerical-integration

The package `` Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; `` provides a very useful function `GaussianQuadratureWeights[n, a, b]` which gives `n` Gaussian interpolation points and weights in the interval `[a, b]` !

Is there a similar function which provides Gaussian points and weights for a triangle (2D) or a tetrahedron (3D)?

Comment: See for example tutorial "MultidimensionalRule" Sampling Points and Weights.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, very interesting hint.